# How do I tell `gar` or `ar` to output `elf32-i386` output?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, unix-ar

When I look at the help output from `gar -h`, it tells me:

```
[...] 
gar: supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 a.out-i386-linux [...]
```

How can I instruct `gar` to create an `elf32-i386` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output type will be the same as the inputs. So if you want `elf32-i386` output you need to give it `elf32-i386` input files